# Multiple blocks in each other, using strong self and weak self to avoid retain cycles

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I did get used to write

```
__weak typeof( self ) wself = self
[smth doSomeBlock:^(void) {
   __strong typeof( wself ) sself = wself;
   [sself callAny];
}]
```

So i avoid retain cycles

But what to do when multiple blocks are nested?

```
__weak typeof( self ) wself = self
[smth doSomeBlock:^(void) {
   __strong typeof( wself ) sself = wself;
   [sself doSomeBlock:^(void) {
       // wself, or sself? my mind is blown
       // what if another block?
   }];
}]
```

Comment: "So i avoid retain cycles" What makes you think there's a retain cycle?

Answer (score 3):

Your first example looks like you're wasting your effort. There's no problematic retain cycle unless: `self` owns `smth` AND `smth` owns the Block AND you're not going to destroy the Block until `self` is destroyed. If any of those is not true, there's no reason to do the weak/strong dance.

The second situation is the same: the nesting doesn't change anything. Is there a chain of ownership from `self` to the Block or not? If no, then it doesn't matter which class of pointer you use.